# Insert blank slide with python-pptx in existing presentation

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm working with the python-pptx library and I'm trying to insert a blank slide at a specific place (slide with the same dimensions).

I know how to delete a slide :

```py
def delete_slides(presentation, index):
    xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst  
    slides = list(xml_slides)
    xml_slides.remove(slides[index])
```

But how to insert a blank slide?

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably come along with a better solution but you could just create a blank slide and then move it to the location you want.

```
from pptx import Presentation

def move_slide(old_index, new_index):
    xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst
    slides = list(xml_slides)
    xml_slides.remove(slides[old_index])
    xml_slides.insert(new_index, slides[old_index])

presentation = Presentation("test1.pptx")
layout = presentation.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[6]
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(layout)
slide_id = presentation.slides.index(slide)
move_slide(slide_id, 5)
presentation.save("test1.pptx")
```